# SAML (or other) authentication flow from non-browser clients

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0, federated-identity, adfs4.0

Looking for guidance to achieve the following functionalities for a web application:

- non-browser SSO
- seamless login

**Non-browser SSO**

The ADFS (IdP) is in a private network, but I would like to facilitate access from any network, meaning I need to capture username (and password if challenged for) at my public domain and then authenticate entered credentials via back-end scripts.

**Seamless login**

As this is SSO, I would like to allow access whit out asking for credentials if a user has an active session with ADFS meaning he has already authenticated against ADFS domain, let's say by accessing his office computer.

---

I was looking into options of SAML ECP, OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect, LDAP but none seem to be solving my requirements whit out an overhead.

*SAML-driven SSO* can not be accessed from any network as it's browser-based thus will not be able to access private network IdP.

*LDAP* does not have private-network limitation but as far as I know, can not facilitate seamless login in such way as SAML can.

*OAuth/OpenID* seems to be solving totally different challenges around authentication/authorisation.

Comment: SAML is not browser-based, it uses HTTP as a transport in some profiles and that's as "browser"-based as it gets. OpenID Connect solves the same problem as SAML...and it also uses HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Open Id Connect and OAuth 2.0 are the [preferred options](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html) since they are JSON based protocols that are browser / mobile friendly.

If you want users to be able to login from any network then the standard way to do it is to make the Authorization Server available over the internet.

For a Microsoft based solution this is how an industry standard solution might work:

- Use Azure AD as an Authorization Server (AS)
- In non intranet scenarios, eg mobile apps, you login via Azure AD credentials
- In intranet scenarios Azure can redirect browsers to your on premise IDP
- It is also possible to sync credentials from on prem to Azure AD

Of course this requires an investment in infrastructure and the work involved is not trivial, but you would have very good options once done.

Comment: Thanks for the link it was a good read. Sadly, the Cloud AD is not an option. It's almost like my service (being public domain) needs to act as Cloud AD in the scenario when it's being accessed from internet (non-intranet). It does seem that OPIC/OAuth are the only options in my case...